# Key length not 128/192/256 bits when trying to initialize Bouncy Castle cipher in Java

Tags: java, aes, bouncycastle

I'm trying to encrypt a payload starting from a password using Bouncy Castle 1.58 (org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk15on:1.58):

```
import org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider;

import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.SecretKey;
import javax.crypto.SecretKeyFactory;
import javax.crypto.spec.PBEKeySpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.PBEParameterSpec;
import java.security.SecureRandom;
import java.security.Security;

public class Scratch {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        int keyLength = 128;

        Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());

        String password = "password";

        SecureRandom randomGenerator = new SecureRandom();
        byte[] salt = randomGenerator.generateSeed(128 / 8);
        PBEKeySpec keySpec = new PBEKeySpec(password.toCharArray(), salt, 872791, keyLength);
        SecretKeyFactory secretKeyFactory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA512");
        SecretKey passwordKey = secretKeyFactory.generateSecret(keySpec);
        System.out.println("passwordKey: " + passwordKey);
        System.out.println("passwordKey.getEncoded(): " + Arrays.toString(passwordKey.getEncoded()));
        System.out.println("passwordKey.getEncoded().length: " + passwordKey.getEncoded().length);
        System.out.println("passwordKey.getFormat():" + passwordKey.getFormat());
        System.out.println("passwordKey.getAlgorithm(): " + passwordKey.getAlgorithm());

        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/GCM/NoPadding", "BC");
        PBEParameterSpec parSpec = new PBEParameterSpec(salt, 872791);
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, passwordKey, parSpec);
    }
}
```

and this is the error I get:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.symmetric.util.BaseBlockCipher$InvalidKeyOrParametersException: Key length not 128/192/256 bits.
    at org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.symmetric.util.BaseBlockCipher.engineInit(Unknown Source)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.init(Cipher.java:1394)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.init(Cipher.java:1327)
    at tech.dashman.dashman.Scratch.main(Scratch.java:30)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Key length not 128/192/256 bits.
    at org.bouncycastle.crypto.engines.AESEngine.generateWorkingKey(Unknown Source)
    at org.bouncycastle.crypto.engines.AESEngine.init(Unknown Source)
    at org.bouncycastle.crypto.modes.GCMBlockCipher.init(Unknown Source)
    at org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.symmetric.util.BaseBlockCipher$AEADGenericBlockCipher.init(Unknown Source)
    ... 4 more
```

and the debugging output looks like this:

```
passwordKey: com.sun.crypto.provider.PBKDF2KeyImpl@f00a68fe
passwordKey.getEncoded(): [122, -75, -99, 114, -123, 71, 6, 50, 45, 64, -97, 10, -66, 7, 110, 17]
passwordKey.getEncoded().length: 16
passwordKey.getFormat():RAW
passwordKey.getAlgorithm(): PBKDF2WithHmacSHA512
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Is the key in fact 256-bits? Note that a 128-bit key is as secure as a 256-bit key, that is neither are susceptible to brute force attacks. Of course a larger key is more manly in the same way as a red car.  See {Why most people use 256 bit encryption instead of 128 bit?](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/19762/5121).

Comment: Neither size, 128, 192 nor 256 work.

Comment: Given the error message: `Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Key length not 128/192/256 bits.` what is the actual key that is failing?

Comment: @zaph: technically, I don't know. passwordKey.getEncoded().length is 32 (when I specify a 256bit key), so, that looks ok.

Comment: `passwordKey` `getEncoded90`, `getFormat()` & `getAlgorithm()`. See [Interface Key](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/Key.html#getEncoded())

Comment: @zaph: I added printing those values to the question.

Comment: I assume you have installed the unlimited crypto extensions successfully. A starting point might be to back off to a 128-bit key to eliminate one variable.

Comment: @zaph: I have, but let's go back to 128 and simplify things.

Comment: In the sprit of simplifying things go to a static key byte array. IOW a [mcve] with emphasis on minimal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem! I wasn't specifying the provider when getting the secret-key factory. Replacing:

```
SecretKeyFactory secretKeyFactory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA512");
```

for

```
SecretKeyFactory secretKeyFactory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA512", "BC");
```

Made this example work.

Comment: The exception does not make much sense if this is the solution. Why would Bouncy Castle throw an invalid key exception when the problem was the provider? Looking at `passwordKey.getEncoded()`, some of the characters have the high bit set. Are they combined into a single code point such that the key is smaller than it appears? Maybe Bouncy Castle is more forgiving, and treats it as a byte array without combining characters?

Comment: @jww I believe Pablo did more changes, indeed this code itself should not help (it even may produce another exception, as IMHO the defined key spec is not provided by BC)

Answer (score 2):

For AES you need an AES secret key, which is based on the PBE secret key:

```
SecretKeyFactory secKeyFactory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA512");
KeySpec spec = new PBEKeySpec(password, salt, iterations, 128);
SecretKey pbeSecretKey = secKeyFactory.generateSecret(spec);
SecretKey aesSecret = new SecretKeySpec(pbeSecretKey.getEncoded(), "AES");

Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/GCM/NoPadding","BC");
```